# Is having evil thoughts considered as Shirk?

Tags: shirk, evil-thoughts, fear

Salam Aleikum my brothers and sister

I wanna ask when a evil thought is coming to my head, is that shirk?

Not too long ago, a voice said in my head **“I trust the Shaytan”**,  I immediately panicked and now I don’t know, if it’s shirk.

I’m so scared of it and I can’t get it out, of my head. These evil thoughts come a lot, I face these voices and bad thoughts about Allah Swt every single day. I’m panicking every single day because of these thoughts and I always fear if it’s my own fault. Even when I am trying to worship Allah Swt they are still in my head.

I hope you guys can help.

Comment: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/72042/image-prohibition-in-islam https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/72042/image-prohibition-in-islam

Answer (score -1):

Assalamu A'laikum!

After the salah of Fajr (in the morning) & Salah of Maghrib (in the evening) recite this 3 times)

[image: Istegfar]

Then recite Three times
[image: durood]

Then recite this 3 times [image: Audhubillahis sami...]

**Then recite this 3 times** [image: Bismillah-hillaji....]

> Blockquote

**Now Please recite Aytul Qursi Surah Baqarah Verse 102 "quran(dot)com/2/102" 3 times in the morning and evening and 1 time after every salah!**

**Then recite one by one after both the morning salah and the evening salah
Surah Ikhlas, quran(dot)com/112 (3 times),
then Surah Falaq quran(dot)com/113 (3 times),
& then Surah Naas quran(dot).com/114 (3 times)**

> Blockquote

Then recite this 3 times or at least 1 time [image: Surah Al Muminun (23) Ayah 97-98]

Then recite this 3 times or at least 1 time [image: Surah Al Fussilat (41) Ayah 36]

> Blockquote

**Then recite this 1 time "Saidul Istigfar"** [image: Saidul Istigfar]
**Then recite the Durood 3 times**!!

> Blockquote

**Please find someone to teach you the dua and AL Quran verses in Arabic Pronunciation and please don't recite them in English (transliteration, it is for your reference only for help but you must recite them in proper Arabic pronouncing.**

> Blockquote

**Please follow this page (myislam(dot)org/dua-for-bathroom/) for learning the simple Two Duas for entering the toilet and leaving the toilet.**

> Blockquote

**Please note: Before Sleep You must recite this 1-time Saidul Istegfar and Durood 3 times**

> Blockquote

**Now Please recite Aytul Qursi  1 time (mentioned above)**

> Blockquote

***Then Surah Ikhlas, then Surah Falaq, then Surah Naas
blow to your palms and gently rub your hands in your full body
(repeat this in total 3 times)***
then go to sleep...

> Blockquote

**& One more thing (Please stay away from PORN, anything vulgar, nudity, disgraceful acts, just in case please don't take otherwise)**

> Blockquote

please replace the word (dot) with **.** point for the links I have mentioned.

> Blockquote

***You will be protected from everything by the will of Allah (swt)!***
**Jazakallahu Khairan, May Allah help you in this life and afterlife (Amin!)**

Answer (score -1):

Also, Please remember to recite

[image]

and

[image]

**Before reciting Aytul Qursi **

**and recite**

[image]

**before Surah Ikhlas and Surah Falaq and Surah Naas.**

> Blockquote

**Now: Please recite last Two verses of Surah Baqarah after Aytul Qursi https://quran.com/2/285 and https://quran.com/2/286 before you sleep.**
** At least once**

> Blockquote

**According to verse 286, anything comes to your mind without your will, Allah (swt) will not punish you. However,  the reason, you have had this thing is called waswasah. and do not pay attention to it never pay attention to it. more you pay attention it increases. Please note IT IS NOT SHIRK if YOU DO NOT BELIEVE IT no matter what ever evil the thought could be.**